# regex in scanf c?

Tags: c, regex, parsing, printf

Is there any regex/way to solve the problem: 
I want to parse a file in C which is always like this:

> number (word) number

```
fscanf(file, "%d (%s) %d", ...)
```

works but not when it's a compound word,
how can i do this ?

---

[update from [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48036205/regex-in-scanf-c#comment83042518_48036205)]

There are a lot of other variable actualy but I only said 3 to make it easier, no superfluous. yes it [word] can contains whitespace

Comment: look at a lexical analyzer (say e.g. flex) and use that. flex will generate C code for you. Now since this is my opinion, it demonstrate that this question is going to get opinionated answers, and therefore I will vote to close it

Comment: What does this has to do with printf?

Comment: @AhmedMasud: I feel this would be a somewhat over-engineered approach.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @alk :P that is kind of an issue with this isn't it

Comment: Welcome to [so]... Please have a look at [mcve] to learn how to get specific help. You are not sharing what you've tried. This is actually a trivial problem to solve in C that has many good answer both on [so] and elsewhere, please share your actual code that you've attempted

Comment: You could use `fgets()` and do the parsing yourself.

Comment: The [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) function doesn't support regular expressions, but it has a format `"%["` that could be used for this.

Comment: What is a "componed" word?  Do you mean it fails when the string in the parentheses contains whitespace?

Comment: fgets way to long if I can avoid this... There are a lot of other variable actualy but I only said 3 to make it easier, no superfluous.
yes it can contains whitespace

Comment: also this question is *not* related to regular expressions

Comment: I don't know Ahmed, I though it was a track. I thought about a regex which could take caracters (with space) between parenthesis

Comment: Try `"%d (%[^)]) %d"`.

Comment: If you really have a lot of different situations that you need to tokenize then my original comment about utilizing flex may actually be the most efficient wayt

Answer (score 0):

Just read in the whole line and use `strtok()` to break up the string in three parts by searching for `(` and `)` as delimiters.

After that just do `sscanf()` part by part.

```
char  line[256];  // Make sure this is large enough for all possible lines.
char* left;
char* word;
char* right;

// Read the line from file. Make sure you don't go over its size.

left  = line;
word  = strtok(line, "(");
right = strtok(NULL, ")");
```

Because `strtok()` replaces `(` and `)` with `\0`, you already have a pointer to your `word`. Now you just get the two integers using `sscanf()`.

```
int leftInt;
int rightInt;
sscanf(left,  "%d", &leftInt);
sscanf(right, "%d", &rightInt);
```

This is a simple lexical analyser without using [Lex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lex_(software)) that @AhmedMasud was mentioning.

Another term for 'Lexical analyser' is 'tokenizer', that's where the name of the function `strtok()` comes from.

You don't have to worry about what characters/spaces/... is between `(` and `)` as long as you can guarantee it's not `(` or `)`.

Comment: As we have not been give detailed specifications on how "word" might look: Your approach will fail if "word" contained either `(` or `)`.

Comment: @alk Do you really think the OP is that stupid or that he could have meant something with special characters when talking about 'word' and 'compound word'? Also, what kind of parsing did you have in mind when commenting "You could use fgets() and do the parsing yourself."?

Comment: I'd have gone for the first and the last blank using `strchr()` and `strrchr()`.